# Workflow EventReceiver (how modify init (start) form of approval workflow)

Tags: 2010, development, workflow, workflow-activity

My problem is:

I think that I should create event receiver on SP approval workflow. My custom code in that "receiver" should need to do modification to init form (properties) of that workflow. Precisely it need to calculate and display value for approvers field (which is defined on init form of workflow upon I click "Publish major version" which triggers starting of my workflow).

For now, I am blocked because I don't how do that and is this even possible?

Please any suggestion (or useful link) will be greatly appreciated!